# WPF setting focus to Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, focus

Just drop a button and a combobox inside a new WPF application

On the button click simply set the focus to the combobox with a comboBox1.Focus() (or anything else possible)

questions :

1- When setting focus from code (with focus()) the combobox never receive the focus.  why?

2- When navigating with the Tab key the combobox receive the focus and display a kind of focus selector around the control?  is there any way to do the same (a real focus) from code?

Thanks

Comment: What's the code you have so far ?

Comment: nothing just comboBox1.SetFocus() with a standard combobox with default properties (focusable of course)

Comment: but I also tried Keyboard.FocusManager.SetFocusedElement , Keyboard.Focus(element), getting focus to the textbox inside, routed event with mousedown  etc..etc..

Answer (score 2):

Focus style (dotted line ) is only appeared when we used Tab key ..thats why combobox is only taken focus not focus style on button click..but you can show focus by opening dropdown like below

```
     private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {                              
         Cmb.Focus();
         Cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;                                
    }
```

Sorry if I am wrong to your approach.

Comment: I dont want to open the dropdown to set the focus. Focus style (dotted line ) is only appeared when we used Tab key ....really? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is actually working - the problem is that in non-editable ComboBox it is hard to tell visually if the focus is there.

If you add IsEditable="True" you will see it the cursor will move to the ComboBox when you click the button.

The focus selector you see with the Tab key is keyboard focus.  Try this: on your app, without making ComboBox editable, navigate to the button and press SPACE.  You will see the rectangle selection appear around the ComboBox, because the keyboard focus will move there.

Comment: Yes Focus() seems to set a simili focus to the combobox (if you press the arrow key you will see that a kind of focus is on the combobox) but still no focus with the dotted line.  Same thing about the space key and IsEditable (it change nothing)

Comment: I actually tried your repro by making a new WPF project in VS 2013, and the focus is set - calling either CobmoBox.Focus() or Keyboard.Focus(ComboBox) allows the combobox to accept keyboard input (arrow keys will start scrolling through the items).  There's no visual indication though, unless IsEditable is set to true.  Are you specifically looking for the visual indicator?  In your repro, is the focus actually being set?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a way to set the visual indicator (dotted rectangle).  With focus() the focus is actually being set but without "indicator".   (BTW my control is inside a datagrid I just want to have a uniform look depending if the go to the control with the tab key or with the mouse)

Answer (score 0):

Read about selectionboxitem of the combobox which is responsible for selection in comobox edit area. Try setting the IsSelected along with the Focus property.

There are lots of new things on focus handling as compared to Winforms where it was just select and focus. Check the API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: selectionBoxItem is just a simple string.  Cant find anything in the API to set the focus like when using tab to go to the combobox (focus with dotted line )

Comment: Reason for not getting the hovered line is that when we click the button focus is "about to go to button" and then before the button focus, in button click we move the focus to another control so line is not getting drawn.  I tried doing the comboxbox focus in MouseEnter of button and woahh...it works as expected. I am looking what more we need here and will get back to you. Hope you understood the explanation

Comment: No its not working at all...It has nothing to do with the click event. (the click button was just an example to launch the code...you will have the same problem anywhere else (ex loaded))

Comment: This brings the dotted line in my sample. I did nothing but combobox.focus in button mosue enter and I get the dotted box :

void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Focus();
        }

Comment: Thanks....for me it work only by pressing spacebar on the button (not with the mouse) Cant use this solution :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have restyled the combobox, be careful with "OverridesDefaultStyle".  Setting this to true can hide the dotted focus rectangle.